# Ruby => operator

Tags: ruby, syntax

Where can I find an explanation of what the `=>` operator means in Ruby?

For example,

```
class Acct < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :email_address, :on => :create
end
```

what is the `=>` operator doing in this case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The symbol "=>" is not an operator. It's just a syntactic means to express that there is a relationship of "key-value" between the other two elements. It's used to define hashes (or associative arrays, as they're called in some other languages, eg. PHP). In this sense, because "=>" it's not an operator, it doesn't do anything (so as symbols "[" and "]" don't do anything when used to define an array). If you are still confused, have a look into the Hash Ruby class and compare it to the Array class.

Comment: Confusingly, the {braces} to define a hash are optional when it's passed to a method, which makes it look like keyword arguments, as in this example: """def f(x) x end; f :a => :b, :c => :d""" #=> {:c=>:d, :a=>:b}

Answer (score 9):

#### The "*Hash Rocket*" Syntax

The symbol is not an operator, just part of the syntax that is used to define a literal Hash object. It is often called a *hash rocket*.

Normally, a literal hash object would be defined something like this:

```
a = { :x => 1, :y => 2 } # same thing as: a = Hash.new; a[:x] = 1; a[:y] = 2
```

It could be passed to a method, of course:

```
def f(x); end; f({:x => 1, :y => 2})
```

As it happens, when a hash is passed as the last parameter to a method, the `{}` part of the object literal can be dropped:

```
f(:x => 1, :y => 2)
```

The parens are also optional, so we get things like:

```
f :x => 1:, :y => 2 # and of course...
validates_confirmation_of :password, :email_address, :on => :create
```

Finally (in modern Ruby only) for the specific case where the hash key is a symbol, you can write *key* **:** *value*, so:

```
f x: 1, y: 2 # not to mention...
validates_confirmation_of :password, :email_address, on: :create
```

Note here that method calls can be made within class definitions. They get executed like any other method call, but at the time of the definition. They are particularly useful for a package like Rails that does lots of metaprogramming to extend the language and the library objects for its application domain.

Comment: This is the only answer to this question that actually provides actionable information.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the accepted answer (it's not an operator), think of it basically in the same way as a comma.

```
{ "foo" => "bar", "a" => "b" }
```

The comma separates each pair in the hash, the `=>` separates the key and the value inside the pair.